# Querying two RDF graphs in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I have two RDF knowledge bases

KB1 (`path/to/file1.rdf`) wkich includes the two following triples

```
a b c
a f e
```

and KB2 (`path/to/file2.rdf`) with the following triple:

```
c t p
```

I want to get all paths include ones like `?a ?b ?c` & `?c ?t ?p` as `c` is common.

How can I do that in SPARQL?

Comment: Loading both files and run the SPARQL query?

Answer (score 0):

In case of two KB, it is what we call a "Federated Query". Here is an example :

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  SERVICE URI_for_path/to/file1.rdf { 
    ?a ?b ?c .  
    OPTIONAL { 
      SERVICE URI_for_path/to/file2.rdf { 
        ?c ?t ?p . } }
  }    
}
```

You will get `?t ?p` only if it exists by the way.

Simpliest way is to load both files in a single KB and therefore have a simple query :

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?a ?b ?c .  
    ?c ?t ?p .   
}
```